# Are there any exceptions in removing curly braces for an "if" statement?

Tags: c, if-statement, curly-braces, nested-if

I am a computer science student, and some time ago our professor explained us that in C language we can remove curly braces when there's only one statement like:

```
if (a)
  do b
```

but we can't do something like this:

```
if(a)
  do b
  do c
```

because that would be doing more than one statement.

But it also told us that there's an exception about removing curly braces, something we can't do even if it's only one statement. I did a lot of search but the only thing I found is that I can't do that in a do-while loop, but we are talking about if statements, any help?

Edit: we were also talking about nested if statements, maybe it's about that?

Comment: Never heard of or ran into any situation where `{}` was required for an `if` statement.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can also remove the braces of a `do`-`while` loop.

Comment: Perhaps your professor's exception is stylistic rather than for syntactic reasons.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else#C

Comment: a variable declaration like `int n = 1;` is a single statement, but if placed in curly braces `{ int n = 1; }` it belong to another context and it not accessible from the rest of that context.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You professor is probably talking about a situation like this:

```
if (a)
    if (b)
        printf("a and b\n");
else  // this goes with the inner "if"
    printf("not a\n");
```

Contrary to what the indentation suggests, the `else` is not associated with the outer `if` statement but with the inner `if` statement.  In this case you need to add curly braces to the body of the outer `if` for the `else` to be associated properly:

```
if (a) {
    if (b)
        printf("a and b\n");
}
else
    printf("not a\n");
```

It's best to always use braces for the bodies of conditional and looping constructs to prevent this kind of ambiguity and the bugs that go with them.

Comment: This is called the dangling `else` ambiguity and compilers are built to match the `else` with the closest `if`.

Comment: Alright that seem very good, and it's probably that; but maybe something that gives a compile error?                                                            Edit:  I was also thinking about declaring a variable on a "statement-only-if", that would just basicly destroy the new variable, making it useless.

Comment: @cmaster Ok, thanks. I'm pretty sure it's the dangling else then, since we were also talking about nestes if statements.

Comment: @WhiteNoise Btw: google "goto fail bug" for a high-profile, real world example ^^

Comment: @WhiteNoise Forget about my comment about compiler error not possible with an `if()`. It's wrong. See Antti Haapala's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53284483/2445184) for details. I'm going to delete my wrong comment now.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it is always possible to use a single statement without braces. But what if you don't have *any* statements:

```
if (ham)
    int eggs = spam();
```

does not compile because `if` needs to guard exactly *one* statement.

```
if (ham) {
    int eggs = spam();
}
```

does. There is one compound statement with a declaration with an initialization that calls a function; and 0 statements. Not really useful as such of course, because the variable is unused otherwise...

Comment: Excellent, you actually found a *syntactical* impossibility :-)

Comment: @cmaster but it is not "only one statement"  ;)

Comment: Isn't a variable definition also a single statement? Just not the type of statement that's allowed as an `if()` body?

Answer (score 1):

> But it also told us that there's an exception about removing curly braces, something we can't do even if it's only one statement.

I believe your professor is trying to teach you best practices. Even though we *can* write `if` statements without curly braces as far as the C language is concened, we should never do so. It is not really a subjective, personal style preference, but a matter of program safety.

Because it is very easy to write bugs like this:

```
if ((err = SSLHashSHA1.update(&hashCtx, &signedParams)) != 0)
    goto fail;
    goto fail;  /* MISTAKE! THIS LINE SHOULD NOT BE HERE */
```

The 2nd `goto` will always be executed, which wasn't intended. I dare to state that every single C programmer out there who allows this style, has also written this bug. I sure did now and then myself, before I stopped using that style entirely.

For this safety reason, well-known coding standards such as CERT-C and MISRA-C ban the use of `if` etc without curly braces. See [CERT-C EXP19-C](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/EXP19-.+Use+braces+for+the+body+of+an+if%2C+for%2C+or+while+statement) and MISRA-C:2012 rule 15.6.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to debug when you use macros(multi line) with this syntax. You have to look at preprocessed c code to identify the problem.

```
#define MULTISTATEMENT a=5;\
                       b=5;
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   int a = 10, b = 10;
   if(a == 10)
       MULTISTATEMENT
   else
       a = 3;
   printf("a = %d b = %d\n", a, b);
   return 0;
}
```

This code generates the error. Place {} either around the  macro or around if statement to compile this code.